# Check constraint to ensure that the day value in a date is a specific value SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, constraints

As the question suggests, I am wondering how I can add a check constraint to a DATE type value to ensure the day is equal to 01 only. E.g. '2021-05-01' is acceptable but '2021-05-12' is not since day is 12 and not 01.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a DAY() function for this kind of job. It returns the day (1 to 31) from a DATE or DATETIME field. Example :

```
SELECT `date` FROM `table` WHERE DAY(`date`) = 1;
```